# Kendo ListView: cant refresh (reload) data

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Here is my ListView:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ListView<Entity>()
  .Name("listView")
  .TagName("div")
  .ClientTemplateId("template")
  .DataSource(dataSource => {
      dataSource.Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Home").Data("additionalData"));
      dataSource.PageSize(4);

})
.Pageable()   
)
```

Here are javascript function that must reload data:

```
var someData = "-1";
function reload() {
   // insure that function exists
   // alert( $("#listView").data("kendoListView").refresh)
   $("#listView").data("kendoListView").refresh();

}

function additionalData() {
    return {
        someData:  someData
    };
}
```

I do all as written in [documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/listview) but doesnt see any postback.Whats wrong?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`refresh()` (see [refresh](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/listview/methods/refresh)) only refreshes data on screen but don't reload data. If you want to do so, you have to use `read()` :

```
$("#listView").data("kendoListView").dataSource.read();
```

Comment: Thanks! The documentation says "Reloads the data and repaints the list view.". Looks like the documentation is unclear.